# Modify "Start in" properties box of shortcut with VBS?

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, cmd

I'm trying to create a basic installer and I'm having trouble with the shortcut. The installer works fine, but the program refuses to start with the shortcut that gets created because it is missing the "Start in" box information, how would I go about putting this information in with VBS?

Here is what I have so far, the shortcut gets created and everything else is fine, also the code works fine for other .exe's and launches them fine, just not with this one program:

```
set MYPATH=%CD%
set SCRIPT="%TEMP%\%RANDOM%-%RANDOM%-%RANDOM%-%RANDOM%.vbs"

echo Set oWS = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") >> %SCRIPT%
echo sLinkFile = "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\Shortcut.lnk" >> %SCRIPT%
echo Set oLink = oWS.CreateShortcut(sLinkFile) >> %SCRIPT%
echo oLink.TargetPath = "%mypath%/Myexe.exe" >> %SCRIPT%
echo oLink.Save >> %SCRIPT%
cscript /nologo %SCRIPT%
del %SCRIPT%
```

Edit: Here is the finished working script if anyone needs one to create shortcuts:

```
set MYPATH=%CD%
set SCRIPT="%TEMP%\%RANDOM%-%RANDOM%-%RANDOM%-%RANDOM%.vbs"

echo Set oWS = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") >> %SCRIPT%
echo sLinkFile = "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\My Shortcut.lnk" >> %SCRIPT%
echo Set oLink = oWS.CreateShortcut(sLinkFile) >> %SCRIPT%
echo oLink.TargetPath = "%mypath%/MyExe.exe" >> %SCRIPT%
echo olink.WorkingDirectory = "%mypath%" >> %SCRIPT%
echo oLink.Save >> %SCRIPT%
cscript /nologo %SCRIPT%
del %SCRIPT%
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the Docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xsy6k3ys%28v=vs.84%29.aspx), you should set `.WorkingDirectory`, maybe something like

```
echo oLink.WorkingDirectory = "c:\path\to\folder" >> %SCRIPT%
```

To be on the save side, I would avoid backwards backslashes and variables that need expanding - as in

```
echo oLink.TargetPath = "%mypath%/Myexe.exe" >> %SCRIPT%
```

Comment: Thanks, I just literally figured it out as you posted xD, found the solution here if anyone is wondering: http://www.visualbasicscript.com/update-shortcut-target-path-m39527.aspx

Thanks for the help :)

I used: echo olink.WorkingDirectory = "%mypath%" >> %SCRIPT%